# Bootstrap generate all color tons helpers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using Bootstrap SASS into my project, and I'm customizing it with my own _variables.scss imported before the bootstrap.scss. So, my final SASS file looks as simple as:

```
@import "variables";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Where my own `variables.scss` just overrides the Bootstrap variables (eg.: $primary, $secondary, $border-radius etc).

This way, how can I generate all color helpers (eg. text-xxx, bg-xxx, border-xxx) for all colors and all tons (like `text-gray-300`, `text-green-900`, `bg-blue-200`, `border-cyan-500` and beyond)?

I'm reading [official docs for the Utility API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/api/), but I haven't understood how to use it to fit my needs yet.